# Keyboard for IPA, open back rounded vowel "ɒ"

Tags: ios, ipad, keyboard, software-recommendation, keynote

I need to write/modify a keynote using many characters from the [international phonetic alphabet (IPA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet). Currently, I am doing this on an iPad within Keynote.

I started by copying and pasting the characters, since many of them don't appear while keeping press a key like for example the "[Open back rounded vowel a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_back_rounded_vowel)" `ɒ`.

Is there any keyboard that could be used in order to allow entering these characters by just keeping pressed key <kbd>a</kbd>?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give a try to IPA phonetic keyboards, it is not free, but definitely worth it

[image]

Then add it to your keyboards:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are now at least two, free, apps in the App Store.

Search for “IPA “.

When downloaded, restart your device to be able to include the new keyboard under **Settings** > **General** > **Keyboard** > **Add Keyboard**.

I haven’t found the normal keyboard with phonetics under the/a pressed key, yet. These keyboards need to be switched to, just like including an Emoji.

Comment: Apps in the App Store can be linked to directly.